# How to fix "RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed."

Tags: python, sql-server, revoscalepy

I try to run the example in
https://learn.microsoft.com/vi-vn/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/sqldev-py3-explore-and-visualize-the-data?view=sql-server-2017

```
EXEC [dbo].[PyPlotMatplotlib]
GO
```

I got error, I don't know how to fix it.

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 4
A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
```

An external script error occurred:

```
Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\MSSQL1~1.MSS\MSSQL\EXTENS~1\MSSQLSERVER01\E92CD4AC-875A-4CB1-93CF-1F9271D30179\sqlindb.py", line 45, in transform
    rental_model = pickle.loads(py_model)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 406, in rx_sql_satellite_call
    rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 291, in rx_native_call
    ret = px_call(functionname, params)
RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please show us what you have tried to identify / solve the error you're finding? What have you reserached after the `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'` bit?

Comment: the erorr now:  

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\MSSQL1~1.MSS\MSSQL\EXTENS~1\MSSQLSERVER01\030AA8D5-31D0-4899-A7C4-E8F4ECD4DF22\sqlindb.py", line 85, in transform
    plot3 = pd.DataFrame(data =[pickle.dumps(fig_handle)], columns=["plot"])
MemoryError

Comment: It looks like you're missing some of the required dependencies, did you [install the NYC Taxi demo data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/demo-data-nyctaxi-in-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) first before trying to run the examples?

Comment: In case it helps someone in future, it might be possible to address the `MemoryError` by increasing the memory available to Python by altering the external resource pool.  See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69082468/1714